# How do I identify checkbox value with given HTML element? angularjs-e2e

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e, end-to-end

I need some advice with issue below. When checkbox = checked, there will be attribute value checked=checked and for the unchecks, attribute will not be there and I can't uniquely identify. On a page, there will be checked and unchecked checkboxes. Dev refuses to add additional attribute for me and saying that there must be a way to identify (exist or not exist).

So on my my test page, I have 10 checkboxes with 3 checked and 7 unchecked.

**HTML for uncheck checkboxes**

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" ng-checked="item.unread">
```

**HTML for checked checkboxes**

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" ng-checked="item.unread" checked="checked">
```

My attempt at counting - it will returned exact number and will fail eventually as number may change.

```
expect(element.all(by.css('input[checked="checked"]')).count()).toBe(2);
```

No issue with identifying checked items with attribute - checked="checked"

```
expect(element.all(by.css('input[checked="checked"]')).isSelected()).toBeTruthy();
```

but fails when I check for unchecked item.

```
expect(element.all(by.css('input[type="checkbox"]')).isSelected()).toBeFalsy();
```

Failed result for unchecked item - 7 unchecked and 3 checked

```
[ false false false false true true false false true false]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for unhecked inputs, you can check that there is no `checked` atrribute set:

```
expect(element.all(by.xpath('//input[@type="checkbox" and not(@checked)]')).isSelected()).toEqual([false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]);
```

If it is always 3 checked and 7 unchecked, you can assert the count also:

```
expect(element.all(by.xpath('//input[@type="checkbox" and not(@checked)]')).count()).toEqual(7);
expect(element.all(by.xpath('//input[@type="checkbox" and @checked="checked"]')).count()).toEqual(3);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @alecxe. For uncheck inputs, it's returning me failure eventhough it is expected result.  Expected [ false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false] to be falsy.

Comment: @user2388556 ah, sure, give me a sec.

Comment: @user2388556 please check the update - I think it's okay to just have an aray of 10 `false` items in this case.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. Array of 10 false items works for me. For checked and unchecked items, is it possible to check like greater than 0 or less than 10?

Comment: @user2388556 sure, you can use `toBeGreaterThan` and `toBeLessThan`.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe!. I'll just use     toBeGreaterThan and     to be less than for now. Might be posting another related question soon :) will research first.